# stopAllActions doesn't work on Spritebuilder3.1 and cocos2d 3.0

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

```
@implementation MainScene {

CCSprite * _hero
.
.

}


- (void) stop {
    [_hero setScale:(3.0f)];
    [_hero stopAllAction]
}
```

My sprite _hero has multiple keyframes and image's are changed.

This code(stopAllAction) works when I am using spritebuilder 3.0 and cocos2d 2.x.

However now stopAllAction doesn't work on Spritebuilder3.1 and cocos2d 3.0

[_hero setScale:(3.0f)]; works correctly so I think my _hero is working well.

(I insert this line for test purpose)

I guess it is relevant with cocos2D 3.0 update though,

Does anyone know the work-around way or have the same problem???

Comment: please stop asking if others have the same issue, 99.9% of all cases they don't because the problem is in your code *especially* if it's something that's supposed to work fine. Consider that stackoverflow is to help you resolve your issues, not the place where users share their experiences.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D thanks for your replying , I have researched some forums , but still not sure it is my particular problem or cocos2d problem.but maybe it is because of cocos. I will stop asking like this .